# Where I can find Points for polygon of any country? (For java and android canvas)

Tags: android, android-canvas, polygon, point, country

Where I can find Points for polygon of any country?
I need draw polygons of any country (for the beginning) on Android canvas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this:

http://www.gadm.org/country

here you can find all the points.